# I want to make an item that opens with the navigation menu

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a navigation menu. There will be a language option. When you click on it, English, German and Turkish options will appear under it.
I want it to close when you select the language. Or if you click on the language option again, it will close.

**menu.xml**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/language_menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/language"
    android:title="@string/language" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/logout_menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/sign_out_alt"
    android:title="@string/logout" />
```

NavigationView

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_nav_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu" />
```

activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainscreenBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    binding.apply {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.preparing_fragment)
        bottomMenuBar.setupWithNavController(navController)
        setSupportActionBar(appBar)
        toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this@MainScreenActivity,
            mainDrawerLayout,
            R.string.open,
            R.string.close
        )
        mainDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        kapatImageView.setOnClickListener {
            if (mainDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                mainDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
            } else {
                mainDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
            }
        }
        mainNavMenu.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.language_menu ->
                    language()

                R.id.logout_menu ->
                    logoutProcess()
            }
            true
        }
    }
}

private fun language() {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep NavigationView inside drawer layout and close on item click like below code.

Your navigationview.xml will be like below

```
        <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_nav_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

onItem click item use `drawerLayout.closeDrawer()` This should solve your problem.

I'm assuming your code is working and onClick event is getting trigger. Inside `language()` after performing your task add `drawer_Layout.closeDrawer()` so it will close the navigation view

Comment: can you post the whole code?

Comment: Share your code I will modify and add here

Comment: I shared my code

Comment: check I have edited my answer.

Comment: You misunderstood me like this: When I click on the Lanugage option, English, German and Turkish options will appear in the menu, then when I select one of them, it will close again.

Comment: Okay I got it so u want complete code right

Comment: yes , ı want complate code

Comment: okay i will share but it will take me some time

Comment: Are you doing :D

Comment: Hey didn't get time to write entire did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

create a submenu in your main menu

```
    <item android:title="@string/language">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/english"
                android:title="@string/english" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/german"
                android:title="@string/german" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/turkish"
                android:title="@string/turkish" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/logout_menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/sign_out_alt"
        android:title="@string/logout" />

</menu>
```

Comment: I did this, but I don't want it this way, I want it to open when I click on the language option..